# Create timer with boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to create periodic task that perform 1 time per second. But in my case boost::asio::deadline_timer should not be global variable.

```
boost::asio::io_service _io;

void handler(const boost::system::error_code, int a) {
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(_io);
    //do task
    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer.async_wait(std::bind(handler, _1, a));
}

boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(_io);
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
timer.async_wait(std::bind(handler, _1, 1));
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** I get it. You want dynamically allocated timers?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8c44ff5787e2661)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using Timer = shared_ptr<asio::deadline_timer>;

asio::io_service _io;

void handler(int a, const system::error_code& = {}, Timer timer = make_shared<Timer::element_type>(_io)) {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
    timer->expires_from_now(posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer->async_wait(bind(handler, a, asio::placeholders::error, timer));
}

int main() {
    handler(42);
    _io.run();
}
```

The trick is `boost::bind` binds to `boost::shared_ptr` and keep a copy of it - extending the lifetime of the timer object

---

A deadline timer, firing every second, and not using any globals:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main() {

    thread t([] {
            asio::io_service io;
            asio::deadline_timer dt(io, posix_time::seconds(1));
            function<void(system::error_code)> ll = [&](system::error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    puts("hello world");
                    dt.expires_from_now(posix_time::seconds(1));
                    dt.async_wait(ll);
                }
            };
            ll({});
            io.run();
        });

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "async\n";

    t.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world
Hello world
async
Hello world
Hello world
....
```

Comment: can you explain the ll({}) syntax in the lambda constructor, is it just a default constructor for the system::error_code parameter?

Comment: Yes. `ll` is a conventional placeholder name for a lambda function. `()` surrounds the argument list, `{}` default-initializes an instance of the type of the first formal argument, which is indeed `system::error_code` in this case (the brevity is "nice", but the point is if you switch Asio versions the type may silently change to `std::error_code` and you have one line change less.)

Comment: @johnco3 ^ note that I did notice your question [2 days back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779503/using-a-boost-lambda-completion-handler-with-the-deadline-timer) and I couldn't come up with a concise answer in the absense of precise requirements. Here's a draft that I _did_ have halfway, perhaps it interests you: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pWggz8PYZN/ (I don't have the accompanying answer draft anymore)

Comment: thanks, I saw your link, thanks for being helpful as always.  I'm not sure how I can use this to extend a timer within a lambda though.  I have a gui with an inactivity timeout (which upon expiration should change a widget in the GUI and return the timer to sleep rather than completely canceling it).  Even with a non lambda implementation I keep getting 995 error codes - even though it is more or less working.  These error code 995's are generated when I attempt to extend a timer that is still active.  Very strange.

Comment: I was wondering if you got a chance to look at what you might put in the paste.ubuntu.com/p/pWggz8PYZN extend() method to cancel the existing timer without getting a 955 error and extending the 'watchdog' timer.  It seems that I keep running into a 955 boost error code.   It seems that the template you created was to be used with either a deadline or steady timer (I think other than the time changing in the background they are pretty much the same right?). Anyway thanks for your help so far.  Maybe if you have a solution you might put it on the question I posed about a week ago.  TIA

Comment: The goal is not to cancel the time without getting the `operation_aborted` (because that's ... what you do! You abort the operation). The goal is to "eat" it instead of calling the actual handler (because you are expecting it)

Comment: Like I said before, I've seen the question and [ couldn't come up with a concise answer _in the absense of precise requirements_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032828/create-timer-with-boostasio/28033099?noredirect=1#comment88647123_28033099). Simply put, it's not a problem and you're free to just code what logic you require.

Comment: I will try to refine my question to be more precise - thanks